# jquery img max slider using html and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have lot of images of products, i need to show as slider using left and right arrow keys.

```
<div class="popular">
   <h3>POPULAR FISH TANK AQUARIUM</h3>
   <div>
   <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/xgo1837a9/image.png" alt="" />
   <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/xgo1837a9/image.png" alt="" />
   <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/xgo1837a9/image.png" alt="" />
   <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/xgo1837a9/image.png" alt="" />
   <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/xgo1837a9/image.png" alt="" />
   <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/xgo1837a9/image.png" alt="" />
   <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/xgo1837a9/image.png" alt="" />
   <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/xgo1837a9/image.png" alt="" />
   <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/xgo1837a9/image.png" alt="" />
   </div>
   </div>
```

Initially need to show four images, and then when i click right arrow another four images need to show, like slider.

May i know how to do that, I tried from online, but it didn't help me, so i reset my code.

Here is left and right arrow button: http://s16.postimg.org/7vbt88k2p/prev_next.png

I need to show like [**this**](http://s8.postimg.org/kw1mdbi3p/untitled.jpg),

Can anyone please help me to ix this,?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: This link can be helped you : http://www.jssor.com/demos/carousel-slider.slider

Comment: in the above link you provided is not suitable for my purpose.. thanks